# Establishing inequalities on condition numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I want to establish the inequality that

$$\frac{\text{cond}_{2}(A)}{n} \leqslant \text{cond}_{1}(A) \leqslant n\cdot\text{cond}_{2}(A)$$

where the subscript indicates the matrix norm used, with knowledge that

$$ \|x\|_{2} \leqslant \|x\|_{1} \leqslant \sqrt{n}\|x\|_{2}.$$

I know that $\text{cond}(A) = \|A\|^{-1}\|A\|$ but I do not feel confident in establishing this inequality. I know that
$$\|A\|_{p} = \max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_{p}}{\|x\|_{p}}.$$

How may I put this altogether to show that inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the given inequality we can write $$||A||_2\le||A||_1$$ and $$||A^{-1}||_2\le||A^{-1}||_1$$ Since all of them are positive numbers we can have by multiplying 
\begin{align*}
&||A||_2||A^{-1}||_2\le||A||_1||A^{-1}||_1\\
&\frac{||A||_2||A^{-1}||_2}{n}\le||A||_2||A^{-1}||_2\le||A||_1||A^{-1}||_1\,\,\,\,\,\text{Since $n\ge 1$}\\
&\frac{\text{cond}_2(A)}{n}\le\text{cond}_1(A)
\end{align*}

Similarly you can prove the second one

Comment: Is the implication that the inequalities on the vector norms translate directly over to the matrix norms?

Comment: If you use the definition of matrix norm you will have the same inequality.